# How to validate the time in html text box?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, datetime

I need to validate the html text box (onkeypress) only allow the time for given format :

hh:mm // hh--> only allow the upto 24 and mm --> upto  59

no other will be text was restrict the text box : is always shown in the text box using javascript

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty easy.

```
function validate(form) {
    var hhmm = form.time.value.split(':'); // split hours and minutes
    var hours = parseInt(hhmm[0]); // get hours and parse it to an int
    var minutes = parseInt(hhmm[1]); // get minutes and parse it to an int

    // check if hours or minutes are incorrect
    if(hours < 0 || hours > 24 || minutes < 0 || minutes > 59) {
        alert('NOPE'); // display error
        return false; // stop the form from sending
    }
}
```

I recommend to use the HTML5 `time` input as well. If a browser doesn't support the element (IE, Firefox), it falls back to a normal text input. So it will work either way.

```
<input type="time" name="time" />
```

Finally, to run `validate` when the form is submitted, add this attribute:

```
onsubmit="return validate(this);"
```

---

This will work, but you still need to validate server-side (PHP, C#, Java, Perl, Ruby, whatever) in order to make sure it's a valid time.

If hackers are willing to send you invalid data, they don't have to fill in the form but can send custom crafted data straight to the server. Hence you have to (re-)verify it serverside.

Comment: i need to restrict the value on keypress

Comment: @user279 that's a waste of time and effort, not to mention performance and it will probably cause frustrations at users.

Comment: k @tim. How o seprate nad get the hh:mm in same text box

Comment: ...? You don't have to do anything special for that... The script I supplied will work for you.